# getJSON method in JQuery HOWTO

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

In Firebug I see the request and all the data is present. But in an attempt to even just do a simple alert of console.log they get completely bypassed. What exactly am I doing wrong that the alert is never hit?

```
var feedPage = 1;
var rowsToGet = 10;

$(function() {
var urlString = "cfc/getFeed.cfc?method=" + 'getFeed' + "&page=" + feedPage + "&rows=" + rowsToGet + "&userID=" + 2;
$.get(urlString, function(jsonData) {
    alert(jsonData); // never happens
},"json");
//displayResults(feedData,feedPage,rowsToGet); 
});
```

Comment: More than likely the cfc isn't returning proper json. What version of coldfusion are you using?

Comment: Coldfusion 9 I ran it through jslint and it said it was valid

Comment: can you post your cfc contents too. that might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an error handler to your ajax call to see why it is failing.

```
var feedPage = 1;
var rowsToGet = 10;

$(function() {
    var urlString = "cfc/getFeed.cfc?method=" + 'getFeed' + "&page=" + feedPage + "&rows=" + rowsToGet + "&userID=" + 2;
    $.ajax({
        url: urlString, 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        // remove everything before the opening bracket
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            return data.replace(/^.+(\[|\{)/,"$1"); 
        },
        success: function(jsonData) {
            //alert(jsonData); // never happens
            console.log(jsonData);
            //displayResults(feedData,feedPage,rowsToGet); 
        },
        error: function(w,t,f) {
            //alert(w + "\n" + t + "\n" + f);
            console.log(arguments);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character` is what happens, could it be an unexpected ASCII character or something like that?

Comment: Yes, i would have to see the raw output from the cfc. It should be viewable from the first section of the console.log, named responseText. How are you generating the json? Are you building it manually, or are you letting the CFC generate it.

Comment: I'm using an array of structs and using then letting the CFC generate it through `returnformat=json`. I just looked at the output and noticed at the top of the json there is a random `<script src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: That would be why jQuery rejects it... I wonder what's causing the random script tag.

Comment: As a quick-fix, you could use a dataFilter to remove the script tag, however i would suggest still trying to find a way to remove it from the response at the source(the cfc). Added sample to answer.

Comment: You mentioned an extra script tag in your result. Did you look at your Application.cfc file to see if it's automatically including it?

Answer (score 0):

This could very well be because the return data is not a valid JSON string.
try console.logging without specifying the datatype to be "json" at the end of your $.get call.